# What is the difference between "Unmounting" and "Detaching" in AWS EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I just want to know  the difference between "Unmounting" and "Detaching" in AWS EBS.

Comment: I think unmount is while the instance is running and happen at the OS level, where the storage volume is mount/unmount.  While detaching is happen at the settings/configuring the instance level.  Where you can attach the storage volume to the instance or remove it complete.  So you could have the volume attach and unmount while the instance is running, whereas if you have the volume detach then the volume is no longer part of the instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unmount is an operation you perform at the operating system level. It would make the EBS volume unavailable to any software running on the instance, but from a "hardware" level the volume would still be attached to the EC2 instance.

Detach would completely disconnect the volume from the EC2 instance, and make it available to attach to a different instance.